# Print styles in Fullcalendar don't override abs pos

Tags: css, printing, fullcalendar

My users want to be able to print calendars. I know there is a print CSS file (css/fullcalendar.print.css), but that doesn't override the inline styles that use absolute positioning to place individual events.

I can create selectors to override the absolute positioning or add new classes corresponding to each column, but the problem comes with the fact that the widths and position of the boxes change with every window size, along with the column sizes.

Couple this with different paper sizes and orientations (though I have a media query in place to mitigate the orientation change), and it is impossible to get the events to fit into the columns ([as others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704851/full-calendar-jquery-plugin-multipage-print-is-out-of-skew)). If the user resizes the window after page load but prior to printing, the effects are more pronounced.

Also, since the events aren't children of the days, there is no way to rely on them as a parent for spacing and sizing.

The screen shots show print-previews (with background colors to make it easier to see) of what is happening.

Screen caps at http://tmblr.co/ZUq0Ls18UbU75

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I might be dealing with something similar.

Comment: Nope. Never heard a word. Even tagged it and notified the FullCalendar folks per instructions. In the end we had to set fixed print sizes, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Would you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100185/fullcalendar-print-css-column-widths-not-distributed and see if it's similar? If so, how did you account for the starting position of each event?

Comment: Sorry, AFK for a week. Your issue looks to be the same. I used similar technique to set col widths (but with % instead of px) and used media queries to change left position of event based on page width (since I couldn't rely on page orientation media query). Or at least I think I did. Project over 6 months ago, going off memory.

Comment: I follow about % instead of hard-coding widths. Great idea. The event left positions are my issue currently. As shown in my print screens - they get progressively worse from left to right. (I need say 10 pixels off the Monday event and maybe 50 off of the Friday). I know you're going back revisiting an old issue but any further thoughts on how you set the left positions of the events?

Comment: I set the left position for each column, for eg: .fc-view-basicWeek div div.eventcolumn6, .fc-view-month div div.eventcolumn6 { left: 898px !important; }
I used @media (orientation: landscape) for the alternate layout: .fc-view-basicWeek div div.eventcolumn6, .fc-view-month div div.eventcolumn6 { left: 998px !important; }
I did a diff left position for each col: 0:5px, 1:155px, 2:305px, 3:452px, 4:599px, 5:750px. Your numbers would vary based on text size, widths, etc.